# How do you decide which typed array to use?

Tags: javascript, json, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I am trying to create a view of `ArrayBuffer` object in order to JSONify it.

```
var data = { data: new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer) }
var json = JSON.stringify(data)
```

It seems that the size of the `ArrayBuffer` does not matter even with the smallest `Uint8Array`. I did not get any RangeError so far:) If so, how do I decide which typed array to use?

Comment: You decide based on the data stored in the buffer, or, better said, based on your interpretation of that data.

Comment: Also an`Uint8Array` is not an 8 bit array, it's an array of unsigned 8 bit integers. It can have any length. A `Uint8Array` created from the same `ArrayBuffer` as a `Uint16Array` is going to be twice as long, because every byte in the `ArrayBuffer` is going to be "placed" as one element of the `Uint8Array`, while for the `Uint16Array` each pair of bytes is going to "become" one element in the array.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv you should have posted that as an answer.  You explained it perfectly.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Thanks for your comment. I now understand that the difference has to do with data format. When will Uint16Array be used over Uint8Array? Can you give me an example so that I can understand?

Comment: I'm working on a more complete answer right now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You decide based on the data stored in the buffer, or, better said, based on your interpretation of that data.

Also an `Uint8Array` is not an 8 bit array, it's an array of unsigned 8 bit integers. It can have any length. A `Uint8Array` created from the same `ArrayBuffer` as a `Uint16Array` is going to be twice as long, because every byte in the `ArrayBuffer` is going to be "placed" as one element of the `Uint8Array`, while for the `Uint16Array` each pair of bytes is going to "become" one element in the array.

A good explanation of what happens is if we try thinking in binary. Try running this:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(2);
var uint8View = new Uint8Array(buffer);
var uint16View = new Uint16Array(buffer);

uint8View[0] = 2;
uint8View[1] = 1;

console.log(uint8View[0].toString(2));
console.log(uint8View[1].toString(2));
console.log(uint16View[0].toString(2));
```

The output is going to be

```
10
1
100000010
```

because displayed as an unsigned 8 bit integer in binary, 2 is 00000010 and 1 is 00000001. (`toString` strips leading zeroes).

`Uint8Array` represents an array of bytes. As I said, an element is an unsigned 8 bit integer. We just pushed two bytes to it.

In memory those two bytes are stored side by side as 00000001 00000010 (binary form again used to make things clearer).

Now when you initialize a `Uint16Array` over the same buffer it's going to contain the same bytes, but because an element is a unsigned 16 bit integer (two bytes), when you access `uint16View[0]` it's going to take the first *two* bytes and give them back to you. So `0000000100000010`, which is `100000010` with no leading zeroes.

If you interpret this data as base 10 (decimal) integers you'll know it's `0000000100000010` to base 10 (258).

Neither `Uint8Array` nor `Uint16Array` store any data themselves. They are simply different ways of accessing bytes in an `ArrayBuffer`.

*how* one chooses which one to use? It's not based on preference but on the underlying data. `ArrayBuffer` is to be used when you receive some binary data from some external source (web socket maybe) and already *know* what the data represents. It might be a list of unsigned 8 bit integers, or one of signed 16 bit ones, or even a mixed list where you know the first element is an 8 bit integer and the next one is a 16 bit one. Then you can use `DataView` to read typed items from it.
If you don't know what the data represents you can't choose what to use.

Comment: Impressive answer! +1 for thoroughness.

Comment: If I am not going to use DataView and just need to create a view of the ArrayBuffer in order to JSONify and send it over AJAX requests only to deserialize it, the data format does not matter, I guess? except that Uint8Array being faster?

Comment: You won't see any difference at all. All of them are just "views" - ways to interpret the data. The data itself is stored in the buffer.